# sql select is returning the same set of rows multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with the query and it's showing the same rows multiple times, just alternating between two.  I tested selecting every column from all mentioned tables and don't see differences between the rows.  Note that there should be only two returned rows, and I'm getting over 10.

I think this has something to do with joining the mlc table with the trv table, but I'm stuck on how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
SELECT mlc.click_amount AS memPayout
        FROM tbl_trackvalue AS trv, tbl_tracking AS t, tbl_offers AS off, tblusers AS usr, tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc
        WHERE mlc.tracking_id = trv.tracking_id
              AND off.id = t.offer_id
              AND off.offer_type = 'mailchimp'
              AND usr.id = trv.tr_user_id
              AND trv.tr_user_id =1454
              AND mlc.requested_date = '2014-01-21'
              AND mlc.payment_status = 'pending'
              AND mlc.requested_status = 'declined'
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
SELECT mlc.click_amount AS memPayout
                                        FROM tbl_trackvalue AS trv, tbl_offers AS off, tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc
                                        WHERE mlc.tracking_id = trv.tracking_id
                                        AND off.id = trv.tr_offer_id
                                        AND off.offer_type = 'mailchimp'
                                        AND trv.tr_user_id =1454
                                        AND mlc.requested_date = '2014-01-21'
                                        AND mlc.payment_status = 'pending'
                                        AND mlc.requested_status = 'declined'
```

UPDATE II (Changed again, this time it works.  Thanks for the help.  I'm very new, and realizing now the importance of being explicit with naming joins:

```
SELECT mlc.click_amount AS memPayout
    FROM  tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc inner join tbl_trackvalue AS trv on mlc.tracking_id=trv.tracking_id
    WHERE trv.type = 'mailchimp'
    AND trv.tr_user_id =1454
    AND mlc.requested_date = '2014-01-21'
    AND mlc.payment_status = 'pending'
    AND mlc.requested_status = 'declined'
```

Comment: You are likely missing a join, you should post your table structures or make a http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: If you use `inner join`, you might find that your joins are more clearly distinctive from your filters in the where clause. That will also help you to spot any errors you made in them.

Comment: looks like your tblusers table join is quite useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join `t` on `off` and you join `trv` on `usr` and `mlc`, but there is never any join between those two blocks of joins.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I'm very new to all of this.  Are you saying I need to join every mentioned table with every other mentioned table?  I've updated my code to reflect some of the ideas.

Comment: You don't need to join every table on every table, but you should specify all relevant conditions. If you join without a condition, you will get the number of rows in A times the number of rows in B. You need to narrow that down by specifying the relationship between A and B. In your original query, most of those relations where there, but then you had two groups of tables when weren't related. It's hard to explain what exactly to add, since you didn't specify a table structure, but I guess there should be a link between `trackvalue` and `tracking`, which you didn't specify.

Comment: The advantage of `inner join` is that (I think) it is a much clearer way of writing the join, separating join conditions (relations) from filters (the stuff you put in the `where` clause). Also you can use `left join`, which can be used if you want to query information from A that has a 0 or more relationship with B. And there is `cross join`, which is basically the same as separating tables using a comma, like you did.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Learned a lot about joins today.

Answer (score 0):

to eliminate duplicate rows you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: You can do that, but you should really think twice before you do. Often you get duplicate rows because of a mistake in your query and using `SELECT DISTINCT` might just (temporarily) hide that problem. So only use it if you are sure why you get so many rows, and not as an patch when you are surprised by the number of rows you're getting.